# In freebsd, how to know what options were enabled in kernel during Compiling

Tags: c, freebsd, bsd

After compilation, if one wants to know the different options which were enabled during compilation, how can one find out?

Comment: e.g what you would like to know.. release/debug only? or something else?

Comment: It is in the debug mode. But it would be helpful if info is available for both of them

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you have kernel config options and if your kernel was built with INCLUDE_CONFIG_FILE option, which should be enabled in GENERIC kernel config on recent BSD versions, then you can retrieve kernel config with `sysctl kern.conftxt` command.